# On what ZendFramework version depend the lastest Koala?

Tags: php, zend-framework, koala-framework

How can I know the ZendFramework version that Koala is based/depend on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the version in the file `include_path_version` located in the root directory. For the current version 3.7 see https://github.com/koala-framework/koala-framework/blob/3.7/include_path_version.

Another way to be sure is to install the framework and open the file `Zend/Version.php` and have a look at the constant `VERSION`.